# AngularJS not iterating over my JSON response object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a **Json object**, a response object from a `$http.post` call.

```
{
  "ports": [
    {
      "portColour": "Kth Rd",
      "portLabel": "MCE1000_Ant2_Lo01",
      "portType": "Low",
      "portXdi": "NSMSETBS~MOSAESMN=148823",
      "portTag": "Lo01",
      "portElectricalTilt": 8,
      "portOperators": [
        {
          "name": "MCE1000_Ant2_Lo01_1",
          "xdi": "NSMSETBS~MOSPOPMN=148865",
          "portOperator": "H3G",
          "portOperatorSector": "B",
          "portOperatorTechnologies": "L8/U9"
        }
      ],
      "bands": [
        {
          "name": "MFG00056099",
          "xdi": "NSMSETBS~NSMANBMN=148826",
          "freq": "900"
        },
        {
          "name": "MFG00056098",
          "xdi": "NSMSETBS~NSMANBMN=148825",
          "freq": "800"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "portColour": "Kth Bl/Wh",
      "portLabel": "MCE1000_Ant2_1801",
      "portType": "1800",
      "portXdi": "NSMSETBS~MOSAESMN=148836",
      "portTag": "1801",
      "portElectricalTilt": 3,
      "portOperators": [
        {
          "name": "MCE1000_Ant2_1801_1",
          "xdi": "NSMSETBS~MOSPOPMN=148858",
          "portOperator": "H3G",
          "portOperatorSector": "B",
          "portOperatorTechnologies": "L18"
        }
      ],
      "bands": [
        {
          "name": "MFG00056104",
          "xdi": "NSMSETBS~NSMANBMN=148838",
          "freq": "1800"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "portColour": "Kth Bl",
      "portLabel": "MCE1000_Ant2_2101",
      "portType": "2100",
      "portXdi": "NSMSETBS~MOSAESMN=148846",
      "portTag": "2101",
      "portElectricalTilt": 2,
      "portOperators": [
        {
          "name": "MCE1000_Ant2_2101_1",
          "xdi": "NSMSETBS~MOSPOPMN=148861",
          "portOperator": "H3G",
          "portOperatorSector": "B",
          "portOperatorTechnologies": "U21"
        }
      ],
      "bands": [
        {
          "name": "MFG00056110",
          "xdi": "NSMSETBS~NSMANBMN=148847",
          "freq": "2100"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I set it on the scope ports model.

`$scope.ports = portData;`

In my html file I'm iterating over it ..

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="port in ports">
   <td>{{port.portLabel}}</td>
    <td>{{port.portColour}}</td>
...
</tr>
</table>
```

but I'm getting nothing displayed.

I'm outputting {{ports}} and seeing the above text.

```
{{ports}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add the code where you are assigning the response on scope variable ?

Comment: you need to do `<tr ng-repeat="port in ports.ports">` because the array is actually in the 'ports' key of the json object

Comment: or you can do `$scope.ports = portData.ports` instead

Comment: @KaushalNiraula Thanks <tr ng-repeat="port in ports.ports"> has fixed it. Many thanks!

Comment: ok i will post it in answer section and you can mark it as 'answer'

Answer (score 3):

you need to do `<tr ng-repeat="port in ports.ports">` because the array is actually in the 'ports' key of the json object

Comment: *javascript object